# Attachment Control

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I would like to have your assistance in the next matter:

I have a Power-apps based on SharePoint List. however  I have a patch between screens to fill the entire list,  in second screen I have an attachment control and the last screen I have another  attachment control, however the last attachment control works and save the document. but the attachment control in second screen allows me to attach the document but it doesn't save the document in the last screen when i submit the entire form with the attachment

Patch (TPDD,Defaults(TPDD), EditForm1.Updates,Form2.Updates,Form2_2.Updates);NewForm(EditForm1);NewForm(Form2);NewForm(Form2_2);ResetForm(EditForm1) And ResetForm(Form2) And  ResetForm(Form2_2);Navigate(Menu);

is there any way to send the attachment from form2 to the attachment control in form2_2?

Answer (score 0):

You could save every item to a separate list once uploaded and give it an identifier of the user. Once everything is in place, you can use power automate to take the 2 documents and patch it to your list or just add the references to your main list.

The way you built your app is pretty unclear so no idea if I get how your application is working now, but I would advice the above route